# Autogenerating waypoints to GPX file with QGIS to find coordinates along route

Tags: qgis, point, coordinates, gpx, route

Edit: I was able to figure out how to get the waypoints, I now need help with getting the coordinates for those waypoints in a CSV or JSON format.

I am trying to get geo coordinates for every 0.1 km or 0.1 mi (either is fine) with QGIS(any alternative program is also fine). I was using [Auto generating waypoints to a GPX file along track (hiking path - not as crow flies)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295068/auto-generating-waypoints-to-a-gpx-file-along-track-hiking-path-not-as-crow-f) that question and answer to help me out but I couldn't get the distances to work as it only gave it to me in degrees. I ended up putting 0.0008 degrees and then it seemed like it was working however when I got to the last step it wouldn't let me citing the same error that was mentioned. I couldn't figure out how to solve it with the instructions though.

Overall I have a GPX file and I would like to somehow get geo coordinates along the route at a specific interval.

Comment: Did you "Re-project the trail layer into a projected coordinate reference system" as described in the solution you cite? When you reproject, you can use meters.

Answer (score 0):

> now need help with getting the coordinates for those waypoints in a CSV or JSON format.

In QGIS you can **Export** your waypoints to JSON or CSV, by right clicking on the layer, selecting **Save Features As** and in the popup select the **Format**

[image: Export features as]