# Selecting metres when using QGIS Points Along Geometry

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qchainage

I'm new to QGIS and have been trying to add points every 10m along a track using this older thread as a guide: [Auto generating waypoints to a GPX file along track (hiking path - not as crow flies)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295068/auto-generating-waypoints-to-a-gpx-file-along-track-hiking-path-not-as-crow-f)

However, whatever I do I can't seem to use either the 'Points along geometry' tool or the 'QChainage' plugin to apply these points in metres rather than degrees.

Steps I've taken so far after adding the OSM Standard Basemap to the project:

**Drag GPX file into QGIS and choose the MultiLineString track.**

[image: Selecting tracks - multi-line string]
[image]
(Not sure why the basemap appears stretched!)

**Right-click the track and go to Export > Save Features as**

Then change the CRS to British National grid, which has its units in metres.

[image: Choosing British National Grid CRS in Metres]

and export the vector file, choosing the first option under 'Select Datum Transformations'

[image: Export Vector Dialog]

[image: Select Datum Transformation Dialog]

**Using Points along geometry or QChainage**

With the resulting new layer selected, I go to Points along geometry, but the 'Distance', 'Start offset' and 'End offset' fields are locked to 'degrees' – something I believe should have changed to metres based on the above steps.

[image: Points along geometry - degrees only]

Using QChainage, I can select metres, but then I get a Python error: "TypeError: QgsDistanceArea.convertLengthMeasurement(): argument 2 has unexpected type 'int'"

[image: QChainage python error]

Comment: When you save your .gpx in British National Grid, try also exporting to a different format (geopackage is a good option). Afaik gpx files are always treated as wgs84.

Comment: Thank you @BenW this was exactly the issue. Using Geopackage allowed me to use metres as required.

Comment: @BenW I am struggling to export a GPX file that is suitable to import into online applications like RideWithGPS.

Are there any tips for this?

Current output is just these:
<wpt lat="51.507083688489743" lon="0.026408027347462">
  <name>30</name> </wpt>

...without the actual track included. The desired output would be: <trk><trkseg><trkpt lat="51.50709" lon="0.025976">

Answer (score 6):

GPX file coordinate are by definition expressed as decimal degree using the WGS84 datum. You can't save a GPX file in a CRS with meter as unit. (and yes the QGIS "Save Features as" window is confusing because it use the same interface for all export format even those where selecting a CRS made no sense).

So to add point with interval in meter you will need to save your original GPX in a format that let you use a projected CRS in meter then export back your newly added point to GPX format